# Is there a way to build separately using different Kubernetes configs according to code directory path in the same repo?

Tags: java, kubernetes, build, yaml

I'm not sure how to phrase this so I apologize if the title of the question does not make sense to you.

Due to various historical reasons, I have multiple teams contribute to the same code repo, that serves multiple service endpoints. Currently all teams deployments and releases are done together which creates a lot of churn.

I'm trying to get to this state: team A and B can still share the same code base, but they can deploy separately using different Kubernetes namespace? Like:

- Team A's code is all under `com/mycompany/team_a`, team B's under `com/mycompany/team_b`
- Somewhere in the repo there is a config that does the mapping:

  - `com/mycompany/team_a/*` => `config_team_a.yaml`, that has a Kubernetes config, maybe with namespace `TeamA/ServiceA`
  - `com/mycompany/team_b/*` => `config_team_b.yaml` with namespace `TeamB/ServiceB`

So that they can build their image separately and, of course, deploy separately.

Comment: Without seeing any actual code, conceptually what you describe seems possible.  It'll still be the case that any commit to any part of this repository will trigger your CI system, so the tricky thing here will be figuring out which things have changed and which haven't.  Splitting this up into a (well-versioned!) library repository plus two separate application repositories could be simpler in the long run.

Comment: Having separate library repositories might actually be worse in the long run, since you then need to have multiple repositories in your machine and when the "library" ones changes, all services need to be rebuilt anyway... So for now it might be simpler, but after having several services and libraries it might be a nightmare.
I faced this problem before and this can be solved relatively easy with auxiliary repos, so you can issue a "git diff" and know exactly which services have changes... If you are curious how, you can have a look at my repo.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but from the description of your problem it looks like you actually have two problems:

- The fact that you have separate services code in the same repo (team A and team B);
- The fact that you have several environments (development/production, for example)

The second issue can be easily solved if you use [Helm](https://helm.sh/), for example. It allows you to template your builds and pass different configs to it.
The first one, can also be partly solved by helm, since you can also separate your teams builds using templating.

However, a few years ago, I was working on a .net monorepo and faced yet another problem: every time there was a PR merged to our git repo, a build was triggered in Jenkins for every service we had, even those that did not have changes. From the description of your problem, it is not clear to me if you have a Jenkins pipeline configured and/or if you are also facing something similar, but if you are, you can have a look at what I did to workaround the issue: [repo](https://github.com/pgeadas/jenkinssharedlibrary/blob/master/src/com/pgeadas/K8sUtilities.groovy). Feel free to have a look and I hope that helps.